# Print a Rack Card made with an HTML file and a CSS file?

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm making a rack card with HTML and CSS. Is it possible to print this project, I will need a physical version, or should I just hop over to Canva or similar application? Using HTML and CSS for practice and a unique project for my portfolio. Or maybe I should just use the styling in the HTML file. I'd like to keep both files going though.

Thank you all!

I've done some looking about on Google, but I've not found an answer I'm comfortable with. It seems as though I can print and HTML, but I have not found information about both files together.

Comment: I'm confused by "It seems as though I can print and HTML, but I have not found information about both files together."

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Moob, with the exception of working the CSS inline on the HTML document, I don't know how I would print the HTML file with the benefit of the linked CSS file. I am not always good at putting thoughts into words sometimes.